# What command I should execute to accomplish this:

Tags: linux

```
Open connections: 
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME 
php 3075 lemorpa 3u IPv4 1111738938 0t0 TCP 174.120.62.130:60602->98.139.169.19:80 (ESTABLISHED) 

Recent Site Requests: 

    1.202.218.68 *.mortgagenewshomeloans.com /a/a/Investment/p/p/Loans/Mortgage/News/Home/Loans/szh/home 
    1.202.218.73 onlinemortgagemoiywi.lendersmor /tag/county/ 
    1.202.219.3 *.mortgagenewshomeloans.com /Investments/Mortgage/News/Home/Loans/szh/Business-English- 
    1.202.219.3 *.mortgagenewshomeloans.com /o/w/w/Mortgage/News/Home/Loans/Forex/szh/1 
    1.202.219.5 *.morgagemortgagebanker.com /Loan/szh/selectcity/yellowpages/ 
    1.202.219.5 *.morgagemortgagebanker.com /Loan/szh/selectcity/yellowpages/ 
    1.202.219.6 ratesmortgagemoroito.lendersmor /Contract/Contract_List.asp 
    1.202.219.6 ratesmortgagemoroito.lendersmor /s/a/Rates/Rates/Mortgage/Mortgage/1st/szh/1
```

Hostgator often send me this when they're mad of my CPU usage. I wonder what command they use to display this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First line is an extract from `lsof` command. Maybe a

Other lines maybe gathered from logs but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

The first is the output from `lsof` for single PID showing open network connections:

```
lsof -p 3075 -a -i TCP
```

The second is an extra from a web server log, it appears to be in the form:

```
client-ip vhost-name URI-path
```

You can get Apache to log directly in that format with `CustomLog` and/or `LogFormat`:

```
LogFormat "%a %v %U"
```

though it's almost certainly a `grep | awk` (or equivalent) from a more comprehensive log format.